# Stepping through function with button instead of input()

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to step through a `for` loop via user input in my `tkinter` application.

```
    #! /usr/bin/env python3
    from tkinter import *

    root = Tk()

    def go():
        for i in range(100):
            textbox.delete(1.0, END)
            textbox.insert("insert", str(i))
            something = input('hit enter') #change this idea with pressing button2
            # line 11 what to put here

    def ups():
        pass #2 what to put here

    button1 = Button(root, text='go', command=go)
    button1.pack()

    button2 = Button(root, text='ups', command=ups)
    button2.pack()

    textbox = Text(root) 
    textbox.pack() 

    root.mainloop()
```

Instead of advancing through that function's loop by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the console window (at the `input()` prompt), I want to do so by clicking a button in the GUI. How do I make that connection?

Comment: Do you want a separate pop up input box, or to have the input in the main window?

Comment: main window, using second button is prefered but not must

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a `list` and use a counter to walk through it. If you're really going to just be using the numbers 0 through 99, just use `str(counter)` directly instead of keeping a `list` of `numbers`.

```
numbers = list(range(100))
counter = -1

def go():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    if counter == len(numbers):
        counter = 0
    textbox.delete(1.0, END)
    textbox.insert('insert', str(numbers[counter]))
```

You can bind the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to this if you want.

```
root.bind('<Return>', go)
```

Comment: Only needed adding global counter in function. Tnx!

Comment: Oh yes, forgot that bit. And no problem!